# Can I use Quip starter account to try Quip API?

Tags: quip, liveapps

I have created free trial version of quip starter account and I want to try out fetching data from my quip account using APIs.
I couldn't find developer settings anywhere where I can create platform app to use Quip Automation APIs.

When I launch Quip Console link : https://quip.com/dev/console/

I'm getting following message :

> Looks like you don’t have a team site. You must be part of a team site
> to develop live apps.
>
> Questions? Ask our team and the Quip developer community over at the
> Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Can I just try to call APIs using Quip starter trial account ?
And how to get team site to develop automation APIs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the menu at the bottom left of Quip, you can create a new team site from there. It will be a trial site and it will let you create live apps.

When you're done creating your site, you will notice your Quip domain will no longer be quip.com, but xxxxx.quip.com.

Hope this helps!